# Run iTunes 9 under MacOS 10.14 Mojave

Tags: macos, mac, itunes, macos-mojave

I want to run iTune 9.2.1 on my 2009 MacBookPro on MacOS 10.14 Mojave (through dosdude1's patch). The application launches perfectly fine when being called from Terminal:

`/Applications/iTunes.old.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes &`

(note that I renamed it to iTunes.old to prevent it from being overwritten by system updates.)

However, when trying to launch it from Finder or Dock, the App icon has a 'prohibited' watermark and only throws the following message:

> **You can't use this version of the application "iTunes.old.app": with this verion of macOS.**
> You have "iTunes.old.app" 9.2.1

Also, the system-wide playback controls do not work and I use iTunes to open .mp3 files.

Is there a way to make macOS 10.14 launch iTunes 9 regularly?

Comment: Why 9.2.1 specifically? Most people are content up to 12.6 after which the Store vanished. 9.2.1 is only officially supported up to OS X 10.6. I'm rather surprised it's even 64-bit-capable.

Comment: I just like the interface a lot better than that of version >10. All the functionality I need is already in version 9.

Comment: There's a way to get 10+ working up to Catalina/Big Sur, but I'd guess if it was possible, that 9 would have been included too. https://appleinsider.com/articles/19/10/28/free-retroactive-tool-brings-aperture-itunes-back-to-life-in-macos-catalina

Comment: Please link to the patcher you reference. A quick perusal from DosDude1's site turned up no iTunes patchers that I saw.

Comment: @SteveChambers - presumably the dosdude patcher was to get Mojave on a Mac otherwise stuck on El Cap.

Comment: @tetsujin you are no doubt correct, I just didn't read it that way the first time thru... And it sounds like even Mojave doesn't want to run that version. He may have to step back to an earlier OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment made by [Tetsujin](https://superuser.com/users/347380/tetsujin) and the thus found [Technical Deep-Dive to Retroactive](https://medium.com/@cormiertyshawn895/deep-dive-how-does-retroactive-work-95fe0e5ea49e), I was able to derive this 90%-solution:

1. Open the App's `Info.plist` file located in `/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Info.plist` with your favorite text editor.
2. Change the string of the key `CFBundleIdentifier` from `com.apple.iTunes` to something else, e.g. `com.apple.iTunes9` and save the file.
3. Open iTunes 9 from Finder. Finder relaunches itself automatically.

Done. The 'prohibited' watermark is gone, you can open the app regularly from Finder and Dock and .mp3 files are (in my case automatically) re-configured to be opened by iTunes by default. The only drawback remaining is that the keyboard hot keys Play-Pause/Next/Previous still don't work.